# Could not convert string to float -headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, graph

Although there are many topics on this error I cant find any that have a solution that will help me. I have headers labelled bottom, left, and right in my .csv Excel file, when I try to plot them I get a could not convert string to 
text error due to these headers. How could I solve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Read the input data only once
Bottom, Left, Right = np.loadtxt ("C:Data 2.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1, unpack=True)

# Plot in the first axis
ax1.plot(Bottom, Left, label='Pressure/area', color='b')
plt.show()
```

This is what the file looks like:

[image: can't find a way to link the exact file but it's really only a problem with the headers]

Comment: When asking about an error you get when loading a textfile you need to present the textfile (a minimal version of it) and a code that is specific to this problem (not some plotting commands, which are unrelated). See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

one of the other approches that you can take is to read the csv file throught pandas using [pd.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). This will help you solve your problem.
for example:-
if my filepath is 'example/path/pathtofile'

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = 'example/path/pathtofile'
data = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: You should add more detail, such as a small example. Answers that are just a link to some other place are not always helpful enough.